# 403 Forbidden in AWS ec2 instance using apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi

I am using Amazon linux ami 2.

My django project is in home folder.

`$ sudo grep wsgi /var/log/httpd/error_log` outputs

```
[Sun Aug 16 10:45:11.066491 2020] [:warn] [pid 32311] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.14.
[Sun Aug 16 10:45:11.066495 2020] [:warn] [pid 32311] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.18.
[Sun Aug 16 10:45:11.069981 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 32311] AH00163: Apache/2.4.43 () mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.18 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I add the following lines at the end of the file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
DocumentRoot /home/ec2-user/myproject
#ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
#CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
Alias /static /home/ec2-user/myproject/static
<Directory /home/ec2-user/myproject/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/ec2-user/myproject/myproject>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/ec2-user/myproject python-home=/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/vevn3.8.5
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ec2-user/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

`myproject $ pwd` results
`/home/ec2-user/myproject`
and `ls -l` results

```
total 1476
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user apache   1507328 Jul 28 07:03 db.sqlite3
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user     626 Jul 27 09:23 manage.py
drwxrwxr-x 3 ec2-user ec2-user     108 Aug  9 17:01 myproject
```

I am at stuck from few days ago. I can't overcome the problem. I have already read some tutorials and QA but not satisfied, some are ec2 related but not amazon linux 2 used they used debian.

In addition, `pip install mod-wsgi` also failed.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: what was the error you're getting for  ``pip install mod-wsgi``

Comment: Well, I don't see the `wsgi.py` script in your destination directory, there's only `manage.py`.

Comment: @MarkoE it is under ~/myproject/myproject

Comment: @Kishore very large error message